# Repeat a function if the output is undefined

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, int, calculator

Okay so I am new to C# and I just wanted to create a simple calculator with the console. My question is how could I make the user chose different values for num1 and num2 when they chose to divide zero, or divide by zero to prevent the program from crashing due to an undefined result. I figured I could use a while loop to check and see if answer results as an int, and if not repeat the entire program. How could I check answer to verify the result is an int?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
         public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int num1;
        int num2;
        string operand;
        float answer;

        while ()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first number.");
        num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter which operator you would like to use(+,-,*,/)");
        operand = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second number.");
        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (operand)
            {
                case "+":
                    answer = num1 + num2;
                    Console.WriteLine(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + answer);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                case "-":
                    answer = num1 - num2;
                    Console.WriteLine(num1 + " - " + num2 + " = " + answer);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                case "*":
                    answer = num1 * num2;
                    Console.WriteLine(num1 + " * " + num2 + " = " + answer);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                case "/":
                    if (num2 == 0)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("You cannot devide by zero, please select a different number.");
                        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    else if (num1 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You cannot devide zero, please select a different number.");
                        num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        answer = num1 / num2;
                        Console.WriteLine(num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + answer);
                        Console.ReadKey();

                    }
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First: Always tag with the language in question. Second: Examples should be **minimal**, focused not around the goal you're trying to accomplish but the specific issue you're hitting in attempting to accomplish it, and containing only enough code to reproduce that issue; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

you really only need to check the second value (num2).  You'd want to evaluate immediately after the read.  How you handle it is up to you.  You could loop with a while indefinitely, but you'd also want validate (as with any of these inputs), and give the user an option to quit if they can't understand the directions to input.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is using `while`, see below:

```
            case "/":
                while (num2 == 0)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("You cannot devide by zero, please select a different number.");
                    num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                answer = num1 / num2;
                Console.WriteLine(num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + answer);
                Console.ReadKey();

                break;
```

However, you should think about change to use `int.TryParse` method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as if the user type something that is not a number, Convert.ToInt32 is going to throw a `FormatException` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanset sollution is to extract some methods (select the code and right click with mouse->refactoring->extractMethod).
one of the functions should be "getSecondNumber"
inside that function you start with "enter second number or click "q" to quit.

end you end with if Int.TryParse results with false, or number==0 call your function again (and you'll come to the starting position of "enter second number..."
good luck